# Rock, Paper, Sissors java game from input file. charAt method giving grief

Tags: java

Okay so I have been working on this program for a week and a half, and I feel like I am really close but have been hitting a wall. I have looked high and low for this and I am admittedly not very good at using java's FAQ system. I am trying to pull in a string that contains text in the form `R S` with player1 a space and player2 move. After this I tried to use `charAt(index)` and I am getting an AIOOBE every single time (it cant find any position). I have tried advancing several lines in the scanner just to get one that works and I cant. It seems that it grabs the first 2 lines as `int`, which are the games played and the hands per game.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class rPS{
    public static void main(String ... args) throws IOException{
        int count = 0;
        File myFile = new File("a.txt");
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(myFile);
        int games = fin.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i<games; i++){
            int rounds = fin.nextInt();
            int tie = 0;
            int p1win = 0;
            int p2win = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<rounds; j++){
                String line = fin.nextLine();
                char p1 = line.charAt(0);
                char p2 = line.charAt(2);
                if (p1 == p2)
                    tie = tie + 1;
                else if (p1 == 'R'){
                    if (p2 == 'S')
                        p1win = p1win + 1;
                    else if (p2 == 'P')
                        p2win = p2win + 1;
                }else if (p1 == 'P'){
                    if (p2 == 'S')
                        p2win = p2win + 1;
                    else if (p2 == 'R')
                        p1win = p1win + 1;
                }else if (p1 == 'S'){
                    if (p2 == 'P')
                        p1win = p1win + 1;
                    else if (p2 == 'R')
                        p2win = p2win + 1;
                }
            }
            if(p1win > p2win)
                System.out.println("Player 1");
            else if(p2win > p1win)
                System.out.println("Player 2"); 
            else
                System.out.println("Tie!");     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the string length just after you've read it in, but before you do the charAt? If it is not at least 3 then you will get an exception on your second charAt call.

Comment: Can you edit your code so it is easier to copy from the page?  Otherwise you can post a link to a Gist or a Pastebin.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the files you use?

Comment: line by line (seperated by ; not in the text) 2;2;R S;S P;1;S P

Comment: I commented out all the code below the nextLine() and had it print, to my surprise it Printed "R S" correctly and then errored saying inputmismatchException at java.util.scanner.nect and .nextint

Comment: thank you to all, papa Pearson's was the most helpful when I was able to implement it properly, if i could up vote i would :)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling nextLine() without saving the return value in between reading the rounds and reading the line with the first moves.

The scanner stays just past the integer you read and when you call nextline() it returns the newline character instead of the next line like you would expect.

Comment: without saving the return value... do you mean fin.nextLine(); and then String line = fin.nextLine(); ?? I dont see a return value inbetween there. Thank you so much for the help so far

Comment: Thank you, Thank you. I tried this several times and finally figured out how to run through the code line by line and solved it by fin.nextLine() before the nested loop and printed it out until it was iterating perfect. The code worked 100% with that, Thank you all :)